# Max function with Index/match formua does not return max value

Tags: excel-formula

I have data with a list of dates and times. There are multiple matching entries for most dates. I want to return the earliest time and the lastest time corresponding to each date. **I need to do this without using array formulas.**

I have used a max and Min version of the following formula:

> `MAX((INDEX('2025'!P:P,MATCH(Tables!BZ5,'2025'!O:O,0),0))))`

This formula just returns the firs time associated with the date

> `MAX(INDEX(('2025'!O:O=Tables!BZ4)*'2025'!P:P,0))`

This formula returns a #VALUE! Error

> `MAX(INDEX(('2025'!O2:O450=Tables!BZ4)*'2025'!P2:P450,0))`

This formula returns a 0.

--Expected Result--

Data:

```
Dates    Time    
5/9/19   3:30 PM    
5/9/19   11:30 AM    
5/9/19   2:00 PM
```

Expected results

```
Date       Earliest time      Latest time    
5/9/19     11:30 AM           3:30 PM
```

Based on other board, formulas above worked for others, but please let me know if there is a syntax or other issue I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Office 365 use MAXIFS()/MINIFS():

```
=MAXIFS('2025'!P:P,'2025'!O:O,Tables!BZ4)
=MINIFS('2025'!P:P,'2025'!O:O,Tables!BZ4)
```

If not then you can use AGGREGATE

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,'2025'!P2:P450/('2025'!O2:O450=Tables!BZ4),1)
=AGGREGATE(15,7,'2025'!P2:P450/('2025'!O2:O450=Tables!BZ4),1)
```

If your Excel is pre 2010 then you will need an array formula MAX(IFS()):

```
=MAX(IF('2025'!O2:O450=Tables!BZ4,'2025'!P2:P450))
=MIN(IF('2025'!O2:O450=Tables!BZ4,'2025'!P2:P450))
```

These last two must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Scott, + for the thorough answer. I'm also curious for your opinion on `=MAX(INDEX(('2025'!O2:O450=Tables!BZ4)*'2025'!P2:P450,))`. If I can ask anyone it's you :P

Comment: @JvdV No opinion outside of I find the AGGREGATE easier to read and understand. Plus as an added benifit I can get the 2nd or 3rd or...

Comment: For sure for 2nd etc. Lately I'v been using `INDEX` more often to return arrays. But still wondering if it would have any plussides, for example on any such occasion. Hence my question. Thanks for the response Scott.

Comment: @JvdV BTW the MIN will not work as it will return `0` for all the times that there is no match.

Comment: Right, that's the downfall :)